# Why is the AVPlayer not playing anything?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have a play button and when it is clicked it will play the song in parse. The program finds the song and gets the link, I checked in debug mode, but for some reason it's not playing the song. I played a song in the native music app, and when I click the play button in the app it stops the music playing in the background. I don't think it's a programming bug. Why is it not working?

```
  func playit(sender: UIButton!){
    let cell: UITableViewCell = self.table.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! UITableViewCell

    let playButtonrow = sender.tag

    println(titleatcell[playButtonrow])



    if let nowPlaying = musicPlayer.nowPlayingItem{
    let title = nowPlaying[MPMediaItemPropertyTitle] as? String
    let artist = nowPlaying[MPMediaItemPropertyTitle] as? String



    println("now playing \(title!) \(artist!)")
    println("cell: \(playButtonrow) \(titleatcell[playButtonrow])")

        let query = PFQuery(className: "Songs")
        query.whereKey("SongName", equalTo: titleatcell[playButtonrow])
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                // The find succeeded.
                println("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) song(s).")
                // Do something with the found objects
                if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                    for object in objects {
                        println(object.objectId)

                        println(playButtonrow)
                        let object = object as PFObject
                        let parseAudio = object.valueForKey("SongFile") as! PFFile
                        let audioPath: String = parseAudio.url!
                        let urlParse: NSURL = NSURL(string: audioPath)!

                        player = AVPlayer(URL: urlParse)
                        println(player)
                        player.volume = 1.0
                        player.play()
                        if (player.rate > 0) && (player.error == nil) {
                            // player is playing
                            println("Playing")
                        } else {
                            println("Not Playing")
                        }


                    }
                }
            } else {
                // Log details of the failure
                println("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)")
            }

        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `AVPlayer` code be done on the main thread?

Comment: Right now all of code in the block for `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:` is being run on a background thread. The `AVPlayer` code should probably be done on the main thread.

Comment: I only want the avplayer to play if the object is found in the background.

Comment: Right. But once found, the `AVPlayer` code needs to be executed on the main thread. Try it. See if it solves the issue.

Comment: when I move the code to the main thread I get the error that urlParse is an unresolved identifier since it's declared in the background, should I make this global?

Comment: That implies your code to setup and run the `AVPlayer` on the main thread isn't correct. Update the code in your question with what you are trying to do.

Comment: No. You need to put it back where it was. It simply needs to be wrapped in a call to `dispatch_async` passing in the main queue.

Comment: How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the `AVPlayer` code on the main thread. Wrap the code in `dispatch_async`:

```
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            // The find succeeded.
            println("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) song(s).")
            // Do something with the found objects
            if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                for object in objects {
                    println(object.objectId)

                    println(playButtonrow)
                    let object = object as PFObject
                    let parseAudio = object.valueForKey("SongFile") as! PFFile
                    let audioPath: String = parseAudio.url!
                    let urlParse: NSURL = NSURL(string: audioPath)!

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                        player = AVPlayer(URL: urlParse)
                        println(player)
                        player.volume = 1.0
                        player.play()
                        if (player.rate > 0) && (player.error == nil) {
                            // player is playing
                            println("Playing")
                        } else {
                            println("Not Playing")
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            println("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)")
        }
    }
```